# Will the thread die after his caller will finish the job?

Tags: c++, multithreading

One of my class functions running in infinity loop and accepting clients with the function Server::accept(). So my question is: will userThread die after accept() will finish his job, or it will run forever because of the infinity loop in second function that calls accept() forever?

```
void Server::accept()
{
    // notice that we step out to the global namespace
    // for the resolution of the function accept

    // this accepts the client and create a specific socket from server to this client
    SOCKET client_socket = ::accept(_serverSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        throw std::exception(__FUNCTION__);

    std::cout << "Client accepted. Server and client can speak" << std::endl;

    // the function that handle the conversation with the client
    std::thread userThread(&clientHandler, client_socket);
    userThread.detach();
}
```

Comment: It will continue running - but you should probably rethink detaching it. You'll need to sync manually to make sure all the threads are dead before the program finishes. That's usually more cumbersome than running them attached and `join`ing.

Comment: You might want to consider using a thread pool. Creating a new thread for each client is inefficient.

Comment: Since you `detach`ed it it won't die. However it has nothing to do with surrounding `for` loop in the external function - only with its `clientHandler` procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`userThread` has been detached so the system thread will run until `clientHandler()` finishes or throws. `Server::accept()` will return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

each thread:

1. spawns a new thread.
2. detaches the new thread.

Since #1 happens before #2, you will always end up with a new live thread before the original thread dies.